# Missing Jumbo and MTU for Broadcom NIC?

Tags: jumboframes, broadcom

I have two Broadcom BCM5708C NetXtreme II GigE NICs in my Dell Windows SBS 2008 server.  I would like make one them them Jumbo Frames enabled so that I can add it to my SAN whose VLAN on the switch is already using 9000 MTU.  Broadcom's own data sheet for this NIC claims that it is Jumbo Frame capable up to a 9000 MTU.

The problem is that there is no setting for Jumbo or MTU in the NIC's configurable settings.  There are other settings but just not the one I need to change.

Am I missing something here?  The driver claims to be up-to-date when I allow Windows to search on-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't rely on Windows Update to find drivers. It's very hit and (more often than not) miss.

If this is a Dell add-in card, [download the drivers from Dell](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/index.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen)
Otherwise you can find the driver on [Broadcom's support site](http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/downloaddrivers.php).

Comment: I think you are probably right and thanks for the tip and link.  I'll likely proceed down the path of moving from the Windows drivers to the Dell drivers.  This inherited server was built from scratch so it makes sense that the builder did not go and get Dell's drivers when the NICs were already recognized by Windows.